# MVC Routes - Avoid multiple URLs for the same location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

The default route in ASP.net MVC is the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This means that I can reach the HomeController / Index action method in multiple ways:

```
http://localhost/home/index
http://localhost/home/
http://localhost/
```

How can I avoid having three URL's for the same action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only:

```
http://localhost/
```

then:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

---

If you want only:

```
http://localhost/home/
```

then:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "home",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

---

and if you want only:

```
http://localhost/home/index
```

then:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "home/index",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: So I would need to have individual routes for every controller I want to do this for?

Comment: @Dismissile, you cannot have multiple controllers if you expect urls to be inferred like this. Or if you wanted then yes you need to define them explicitly.

Comment: Is it worth it from an SEO standpoint to do this then? I thought it was bad to have multiple URL's point to the same content?

Comment: @Dismissile, totally not worth it.

Comment: Thanks. I will not waste my time then.

Comment: true, not worth routing hacks for the SEO value but the use of canonical isn't hard and well worth it if you feel there is a danger of these other URLs being linked to..

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the default values kick in.

Get rid of the default values for controller and action.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new {id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

This will make a user type in the controller & action.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I want the one and only one URL to be http://localhost/ for the HomeController. http://localhost/test for TestController. Basically, the shortest URL possible.

Comment: Ah... Well then go with a mix of @darin-dimitrov's answers.  For example the first for home and then do a second once for test as his second sample.

Comment: As mentioned by @darin-dimitrov the SEO advantaged gained by doing this is probably not worth it though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose you are doing this for SEO? Google penalises you for duplicate content so it is worthy of some thought.

If this is the case routing is not the best way to approach your problem. You should add a canonical link in the `<head>` of your homepage. So put `<link href="http://www.mysite.com" ref="canonical" />` in the head of your Views/Home/Index.aspx page and whatever url search engines access your homepage from, all SEO value will be attributed to the url referenced in the canonical link.

More info: [about the canonical tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)

I wrote an article last year about [SEO concerns from a developer perspective](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/07/developers-guide-to-search-engine.html) too if you are looking at this kind of stuff